# how to prevent converting the text into boolean by the use of when statement in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select fti.pa_serial_,fti.homeownerm_name,fti.ward_,fti.villagetole,fti.status,
   ftrq.date_reporting, ftrq.name_of_recorder_reporting,
   case
   when fti.status='terminate' then  ftrq.is_the_site_cleared ='1' end as is_the_site_cleared from fti join ftrq on ftrq.fulcrum_parent_id = fti.fulcrum_id
```

Here, is_the_site_cleared is text type of column which is converted into boolean by the when statement written and hence does not print as 1 and takes as true. I explicitly used print '1'. But this also did not work. My aim is to display '1' in the column 'is_the_site_cleared' when the value of fti.status='terminate'. Please help!!!

Comment: What is the actual data in `ftrq.is_the_site_cleared`? Currently you return the result of a comparison: `ftrq.is_the_site_cleared ='1'`which is boolean.

Comment: well my situation is the column 'is_the_site_cleared' is of type text and when the status is 'terminated' I have blanks in my data but I want to show 1 in this case

Comment: This might be what you want: `case
   when fti.status='terminate' then '1' else ftrq.is_the_site_cleared end as is_the_site_cleared`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using integers rather than booleans?

```
select fti.pa_serial_, fti.homeownerm_name, fti.ward_,
       fti.villagetole, fti.status, ftrq.date_reporting,
       ftrq.name_of_recorder_reporting,
       (case when fti.status = 'terminate' -- and ftrq.is_the_site_cleared = '1'
             then 1 else 0
        end) as is_the_site_cleared
from fti join
     ftrq
     on ftrq.fulcrum_parent_id = fti.fulcrum_id ;
```

From the description, I cannot tell if you want to include the condition `ftrq.is_the_site_cleared = '1'` in the `when` condition.  But the idea is to have the `then` and `else` return numbers if that is what you want to see.

Comment: the idea is when fti.status = 'terminate', I want ftrq.is_the_site_cleared to display value as 1